# modal bootstrap into componente from service

Tags: angular

i'm trying to show modal bootstrap into a component from service here my code

i've tried for hours and hours but i dont see the error and whatelse is in this code,i'm sorry for my bad coding but i'm new in angular

first component

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TableServiceService } from '../table-service.service';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { ModalComponentComponent } from '../modal-component/modal-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-component',
  templateUrl: './table-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-component.component.css'],
  providers: [DecimalPipe]
})

export class TableComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  countries:any[] = []
  @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true }) modalContent!: TemplateRef<any>;
  modalRef?: NgbModalRef;


  constructor(public tableService: TableServiceService,private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.countries=this.tableService.countries_service_array
  }
  openModal_Service(countryId:number, country:any):void {
    //this.tableService.modifica(this.modalContent,countryId,true); 
    //const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponentComponent);
    this.modalRef=this.modalService.open(ModalComponentComponent)
    
  }
 
}
```

second component whit modal in

```
<!-- METTERE LA MODALE IN UN COMPONENTE E FARLA APRIRE DA MODIFICA-->
<ng-template #modalContent>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica Paese</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Contenuto della modale -->
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countryName">Nome Paese</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryName" name="countryName" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_modificato.name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countryArea">Area</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryArea" name="countryArea" [ngModel]="tableService.country_modificato.area | number" (ngModelChange)="tableService.country_modificato.area = $event" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countryPopulation">Popolazione</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryPopulation" name="countryPopulation" [ngModel]="tableService.country_modificato.population | number" (ngModelChange)="tableService.country_modificato.population = $event" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Data Censimento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_modificato.date">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="activeModal.dismiss()">Chiudi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

service ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TableServiceService {
  modalRef?: NgbModalRef;
  country_Copia:any ={};
  country_modificato = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    area: '',
    population: '',
    date:''
  };

  countries_service_array:any[] = [
    {
      id:0,
      name: 'Russia',
      flag: 'f/f3/Flag_of_Russia.svg',
      area: 17075200,
      population: 146989754,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
    {
      id:1,
      name: 'Canada',
      flag: 'c/cf/Flag_of_Canada.svg',
      area: 9976140,
      population: 36624199,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: 'United States',
      flag: 'a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg',
      area: 9629091,
      population: 324459463,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name: 'China',
      flag: 'f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg',
      area: 9596960,
      population: 1409517397,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
  ];

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,private ngbModal: NgbModal) { }

  modifica(modalContent: any,countryId:number, country:any): void {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(modalContent, { backdrop: 'static' });
    const index = this.countries_service_array.findIndex(country => country.id === countryId);
    if(index!==-1){
      country=this.countries_service_array[index];
      this.country_Copia={...country};
      this.country_modificato=country;
      console.log(this.country_modificato);    
    }
  }
  openModal(component: any): void {
    this.ngbModal.open(component);
  }
  
}
```

i'm using ng boostrap and in a last exercise i do it correctly but now when i put the modal in another component it show a simply line grey on the top of the web page and modal dont show up. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you copied the HTML markup of the modal into a separate component with the `<ng-template>` tag. The `<ng-template>` tags are not shown until they are cloned and attached to the DOM, so in your case you should remove it so when the NgbModal attaches your modal component it is visible ant no further action is required.

Working example (You can cut the contents of the `template` properties in the `@Component` directives and paste them into separate files and point at them using the `templateUrl` property like you are doising in your example:

```js
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-component',
  template: `<button (click)="openModal()">Open modal</button>`,
})
export class TableComponent {

  constructor(protected modalService: NgbModal) { }

  protected openModal() {
    this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
  }

}

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica Paese</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Contenuto della modale -->
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countryName">Nome Paese</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryName" name="countryName" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_modificato.name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countryArea">Area</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryArea" name="countryArea" [ngModel]="tableService.country_modificato.area | number" (ngModelChange)="tableService.country_modificato.area = $event" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="countryPopulation">Popolazione</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryPopulation" name="countryPopulation" [ngModel]="tableService.country_modificato.population | number" (ngModelChange)="tableService.country_modificato.population = $event" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Data Censimento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_modificato.date">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="activeModal.dismiss()">Chiudi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, DecimalPipe]
})
export class ModalComponent {

  constructor(
    protected activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    protected tableService: TableService
  ) { }

}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TableService {

  public country_Copia: any = {};
  public country_modificato = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    area: '',
    population: '',
    date: ''
  };

  public countries_service_array: any[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Russia',
      flag: 'f/f3/Flag_of_Russia.svg',
      area: 17075200,
      population: 146989754,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Canada',
      flag: 'c/cf/Flag_of_Canada.svg',
      area: 9976140,
      population: 36624199,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'United States',
      flag: 'a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg',
      area: 9629091,
      population: 324459463,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'China',
      flag: 'f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg',
      area: 9596960,
      population: 1409517397,
      date: "vedere come si prende la data"
    },
  ];

}
```